# SQL 2016 JSON Returning Multiple Recordsets

Tags: sql-server, json, rest, express

I am attempting to use MS SQL 2016 to return an array of JSON objects containing all information in a table. For some reason, the single query returns an array of record sets that contains what I queried for, twice.

```
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

var config = {
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server={localhost};Database={DB};Trusted_Connection={yes};',
  parseJSON: true
}

router.get('/personnel', function (req, res) {
  sql.connect(config, err => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send('Error connecting to database. Error: ' + err.stack);
    }
    else {
      new sql.Request().query('select * from JCE_Personnel for json auto', (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
          res.status(500).send('Error making sql request: ' + err.stack);
        }
        else {
          res.status(200).send(result);
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

My response looks like this, omitting data for privacy.

```
{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            [
                {
                  /* Data */
                },...
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        [
            {
                /* Data - dup of above */
            },...
        ]
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected":[]
}
```

I believe should only be getting a single record set that contains an array of JSON objects for each row in my table, but this is definitely not the case.

Comment: I know nothing about the ORM technology used here, but apparently `result` is an object containing both `recordsets` and `recordset` (the latter possibly just as a convenience property for `recordsets[0]`). You may not want to serialize it as-is and instead just return `result.recordset`, for example. (Given that an ORM *is* involved, `FOR JSON AUTO` is probably not even necessary or desirable -- it will map rows on its own.)

Comment: That's *your code's* response. What does SQL Server return? Did you run the query in SSMS? It won't return anything named `recordset`, `output` or `rowsaffected`. What you posted here is *your library's* result object serialized as JSON, not SQL Server's response.

Comment: Serializing the json response from SQL then sending the result.recordset worked.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deserializing the response and then calling `res.Send(result)`, you can use `res.json(result)` which will perform the JSON deserialization and return the result calling Send in the background.

To return just the recordset/s call `res.json(result.recordsets);`